# sort mergesort in descending order?

Tags: c++

I have this code but I'm doing lots of mistakes used classes
I keep on adding details but for some reason I keep messing it up, what am I doing wrong here?

```
void Sort:: mergeDes(int first1, int end1, int first2, int end2)
{   int* C = new int[max];   
    int indexA = end1, indexB = end2, indexC = end1; 
    while(indexA >= first1 && indexB >= first2)
        if(array[indexA] < array[indexB])   
                        C[indexC++] = array[indexA++];
        else                    
                        C[indexC++] = array[indexB++];
    while(indexA >= first1) 
        C[indexC++] = array[indexA++];
    while(indexB >= first2) 
        C[indexC++] = array[indexB++];
    for(int i = end1; i >=first1 ; i--)    
        array[i] = C[i];
    delete []C; 
}
void Sort::mergesort(int first, int end)
{   if(first < end)
    {   int middle = (first+ end)/2;    
        mergesort(first, middle);
        mergesort(middle +1, end);
        mergeDes(first, middle, middle +1, end);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Descending or ascending is just a matter of using the less-than or greater-than operator.

Comment: `while (indexA >= first1) ... indexA++; ...` - when does that loop terminate?

Comment: You start from end and try to reach first by *incrementing*?

Comment: @molbdnilo The remaining items (if any) of the 1st sublist are copied.

Comment: @Aconcagua I tried decrementing and got a very messy result

Comment: Example: if `indexA` is 0 and `first1` is also 0, `0 >= 0` is true. Then you increment `indexA`, and compare `1 >= 0`, which is true. Then you increment `indexA` again, and compare `2 >= 0`,...

Comment: I think the original problem is that you decided to iterate "backwards" with the same comparison instead of just changing the comparison.

Comment: Oh, funny fact: *'I tried decrementing and got a very messy result'* – but is your result now less messy???

Answer (score 1):

If you do not change the comparison and just iterate forwards, as actually recommended, then consider how your arrays are built up:

You will find the smallest value at the end of the two sub-arrays in question, and these are *neighbouring*! The merged array will comprise *both* of those sub-arrays merged into one another, so it will have a length of a sum of both sub-array lengths, i.e. it will start at `first1` and end at `end2` – whereas `end1` is somewhere in the middle, which would be wrong in any case, no matter if iterating forwards or backwards!

Finally you iterate downwards on all three indices: `A` from `end1` to `first1`, `B` from `end2` to `first2` and `C` will go down implicitly from `end2` to `first1`:

```
int indexA = end1, indexB = end2, indexC = end2;
//                                            ^ (!)
while(indexA >= first1 && indexB >= first2)
{
    if(array[indexA] < array[indexB])
        C[indexC--] = array[indexA--];
    else
        C[indexC--] = array[indexB--];
}
while(indexA >= first1)
    C[indexC--] = array[indexA--];
while(indexB >= first2)
    C[indexC--] = array[indexB--];
```

Then you need to copy back the *entire* array as well – and it reaches from `first1` to `end2` (it doesn't matter if forwards or backwards, you copy the entire one unchanged anyway...):

```
for(int i = first1; i <= end2; ++i)
//               ^          ^
    array[i] = C[i];
```

Allocating the the temporary array again and again is pretty inefficient, by the way. You opted for an object oriented approach anyway, so you could profit from by allocating the array just once and store it in the class. That wouldn't get a thread-safety issue either as you aren't thread-safe anyway due to `array` and `max` members. So sorting might look like:

```
void mergeSort(size_t size, int data[size])
{
    array = data;
    max = size;
    tmp = new int[size];    // tmp: new class member!
    mergeSort(0, size - 1);
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

Or even better: As you implement C++, use a `std::vector<int>`:

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& data)
{
    array = data.data();     // for simplicity, we might retain the pointer
    //max = size;            // max is now redundant as tmp.size(),
                             // so let's drop it entirely
    tmp.resize(data.size()); // no need to care for memory management
                             // manually any more
    mergeSort(0, size - 1);
}
```